# MvvmCross MvxTabActivity is obsolete Xamarin.Android

Tags: xamarin, android-viewpager, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I am updating my game which uses the `MvxTabActivity` class. I noticed it's being deprecated with a message `MvxTabActivity is obsolete: Tab Activity is obsolete. Use ViewPager + Indicator or any other Activity with Toolbar support`

I've searched online but couldn't find a recent documentation about how to use `ViewPager + Indicator` with MvvmCross.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
using Android.App;
using Cheesebaron.MvvmCross.Bindings.Droid;
using Sample.Core.ViewModels;
using Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid.Views;

namespace Sample.Droid.UI.Views
{
    [Activity(Label = "ViewPager!!!", LaunchMode = Android.Content.PM.LaunchMode.SingleTop)]
    public class ViewPagerShizzleView
        : MvxActivity
    {
        public new SimpleListViewModel ViewModel
        {
            get { return (SimpleListViewModel)base.ViewModel; }
            set { base.ViewModel = value; }
        }

        protected override void OnViewModelSet()
        {
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Page_SimpleViewPagerView);

            var pager = FindViewById<BindableViewPager>(Resource.Id.viewPagerView);
        }
    }
}
```

AXML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<BindableViewPager
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:id="@+id/viewPagerView"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/simpleviewpageritem"
  local:MvxBind="ItemsSource Items; ItemPageSelected ItemPageChangedCommand; PageSelected PageChangedCommand"
  />
```

Refer :http://slodge.blogspot.in/2013/03/binding-viewpager-with-mvvmcross-part-2.html

and

http://slodge.blogspot.in/2013/02/binding-to-androids-horizontal-pager.html

Comment: This is a very outdated answer. There is a recent sample of this available here: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-AndroidSupport/blob/master/Samples/Example.Droid/Fragments/ExampleViewPagerStateFragment.cs

Comment: @Martijn00 the link is dead. Could you provide an updated link please?